# Достаю из файла первое слово, но оно не равняется другой такой же функции

Tags: python

С помощью `i.split(' ', 1)[0]` достаю первое слово

```
with open("/home/ddd/Desktop/py/Бот/mybot/data/users/money.txt", "rt") as f:
        f = f.readlines()
        for i in f:
            i = i.split(' ', 1)[0] #Тут например "Самое обычное слово"
            h = 'Самое'
            print(i is h)
```

По идее одно и тоже, но по факту False на выходе, как мне получить True ?

Comment: `is` проверяет, что в переменных находится один и тот же объект, однако даже одинаковые значения совершенно не обязаны быть одним и тем же объектом. Почему бы вам не проверять через `==`?

Comment: кто ж вас научил сравнивать через ``is``?...

Comment: is и ==, дают один и тот же вывод "False"

Comment: Тогда возможно у вас файл не в той кодировке, в какой вы его читаете. Или где-то буквы русские, а где-то нет. Вариантов много, надо всё печатать, проверять

Comment: @ddd значит сделайте что-нибудь вроде `print(repr(i))` и убедитесь, что в переменной действительно написано то, что вы ожидаете (или что-нибудь не то)

Comment: @andreymal я всё проверил, от кодировок, до printa(языки тоже, вдруг русский или латиница) помогла функция intern, спасибо

Comment: @ddd вы что-то путаете. Если строки одинаковые, то == обязательно выдаст True. Если строки разные, то никакой intern не помог бы

Comment: @andreymal Строки одинаковые, просто одна строка это "Ник - деньги" и я достал "Ник" и через другую функцию беру этот же ник, если они сходятся то пропускает дальше вниз функции, если нет, вывод.
Ники были одиннаковые == и is в однинаковом случае показали True после intern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам в комментариях объяснили, как правильно сравнивать строки (через `==`), но я вам могу показать фокус, при использовании которого строки можно сравнивать и через `is`:

```
import sys

i = "Самое обычное слово"
i = i.split(' ', 1)[0] #Тут например "Самое обычное слово"
h = 'Самое'
print(i is h)

i = sys.intern(i)
h = sys.intern(h)
print(i is h)
```

Вывод:

```
False
True
```

*Интернизация строк* - это такой механизм, который есть во многих языках программирования. Он позволяет экономить память, занимаемую строками. При обычной работе интерпретатора он не проверяет использование одинаковых строк и выделяет под них всегда новую память в процессе работы кода, даже если строки одинаковые. А если мы говорим ему интернировать строки, то он хранит у себя специальную таблицу с уникальными строками и выдаёт ссылку на строки в этой таблице, когда мы просим строку интернировать.

Использовать интернизацию имеет смысл только в том случае, если вы хотите хранить какие-то строки весь срок жизни программы и хотите избежать хранения лишних копий этих строк. В других же случаях, когда вы строки просто обрабатываете и тут же про них забываете, лучше использовать стандартные механизмы, тогда память, выделенная под эти строки, будет своевременно освобождаться.

Comment: Ну вот, теперь в продакшене появится строчка `if sys.intern(i) is sys.intern(h)`, и следующее поколение программистов будет гадать, какого хрена тут происходит

Comment: @andreymal 